# Not able to receive option value in angular 2 function upon selection

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1 primary"></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <option *ngFor="let group of instanceList"(click)="change_group(group.name)" > <a href="#"> {{group.name}}</a> 
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Sorry for bad indentation.
Instancelist list is the array of object contain, id, name, groupnumber.
I want to get the value of selected option in my calling method and want to display it in console.

```
function change_group(groupname){
     this.change_to=groupname;
     console.log(change_to);
}
```

The problem is, the given function not even call upon selecting value in dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not leave the option tags alone and just subscribe to the selection changed event in the `<select>` tag

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" (change)="onGroupChange($event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

`(click)` on `<option>` is usually not how to do it.

Use instead `ngModel`

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" ngModel (ngModelChange)="change_group($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let group of instanceList" [ngValue]="group"> <a href="#"> {{group.name}}</a> 
        </option>
```

Comment: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'option'. ("ge_group($event)">
Thanks for answering, actually this error occur

Comment: You need to add the 'FormsModule` to `imports: [...]`